# grails does not include jar files in lib folder to plugins during runtime

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Reports Plugin which is working fine, But when I try to export, i get Error.

> URI
>      /cipg-backoffice/jasper/index
>   Class
>      net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException
>   Message
>      Font 'Times New Roman' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.....

I then included the "DynamicJasper-core-fonts-1.0.jar" file into project's lib folder but the font is still not found.When I run 'grails list-plugins' I don't see the jar file listed.

Please tell how can I add fonts to the grails Project?

Comment: Have you check that "Times New Roman" font is installed in system where your server is running?

Comment: The Font was not loaded on the JVM (http://javaskeleton.blogspot.sg/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Run command : grails clean
2. Add you jar file in lib folder of your Grails App
3. Refresh dependencies

Run and test your application